# How to do a IN query using diesel?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to do an `IN` query with [diesel](https://diesel.rs/) using PostgreSQL 13 to select songs collection from songs table in some id collections. The SQL executed by the database may look like this:

```sql
select * from songs where id in(1,2,3)
```

what I tried to do using rust diesel way like this:

```
pub fn songs(ids: Vec<i64>){
    use schema::songs::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let results = songs.filter(id.contains(ids))
        .load::<QuerySongs>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");
}
```

seems did not work, when I compile the project code using `cargo build` shows error like this:

```
error[E0599]: the method `contains` exists for struct `songs::schema::songs::columns::id`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/biz/music/songs.rs:37:35
   |
37 |       let results = songs.filter(id.contains(ids))
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `songs::schema::songs::columns::id` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

I read the [docs](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started) and [source code demo](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/tree/v1.4.4/examples/postgres) but it was so short and did not mention about how to execute a query by id in a collection. What should I do to make a IN query in rust diesel(`diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }`)? Here is a minimal reproducible [demo](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust-learn).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `.eq_any()`:

> Creates a SQL `IN` statement.

```rust
let results = songs.filter(id.eq_any(ids))
    .load::<QuerySongs>(&connection)
    .expect("Error loading posts");
```

---

If using Diesel 2.x with PostgreSQL, this will automatically be converted into a `= ANY()` query ([docs](https://docs.rs/diesel/2.0.2/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.eq_any)):

> Queries using this method will not typically be placed in the prepared statement cache. However, in cases when a subquery is passed to the method, that query will use the cache (assuming the subquery itself is safe to cache). **On PostgreSQL, this method automatically performs a `= ANY()` query.**

If using Diesel 1.x with PostgreSQL, you should use `eq(any(...))` instead ([docs](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.eq_any)).

> Queries using this method will not be placed in the prepared statement cache. **On PostgreSQL, you should use `eq(any())` instead.** This method may change in the future to automatically perform `= ANY` on PostgreSQL.

<sup>A little self-fulfilling prophecy there.</sup>

Comment: You save my time bro, I searching this for days. Thank you.@kmdreko

Comment: At time of writing - dec 22 - the current version of rust recommends `eq_any()` rather than `eq(any())`. https://docs.rs/diesel/2.0.2/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.eq_any

Comment: @frankster oh nice! That must've happened in the Diesel 2.0 update. I'll edit to reflect that.